# Abrir arquivo (.txt) e preencher os campos no form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, radiobutton

Estou fazendo uma aplicação de cálculos que contém Textbox, RadioButton e Combobox e necessito dessas seguintes opções:
1 - Preencher todos os campos e salvar em arquivo txt;

2 - Opção de abrir esse arquivo txt e preencher todos os campos com os dados salvos.

A opção de preencher e salvar os dados em arquivo txt eu já concluí com sucesso (verifiquei no arquivo e os dados preenchidos foram salvos com sucesso).
Mas estou com o problema de abrir o arquivo e preencher os dados nos campos, mas especificamente o RadioButton, ele duplica a opção que salvei no arquivo txt e desordena todos os itens seguintes.

Segue o print da tela com os dados salvos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E os códigos de Salvar e Abrir:

```
        private void SaveTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SaveFileDialog dados = new SaveFileDialog();
                dados.Filter = "Arquivo texto (*.txt) | *.txt";
                dados.FilterIndex = 2;
                dados.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                dados.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (dados.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    Stream fileStream = dados.OpenFile();
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                    /
                    sw.WriteLine(txtSpeed.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtOwnWeight.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine(txtOwnWeightCounterweight.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtMaterialWeight.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine(txtMaterialWeightWithIncrustation.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtRailGrad.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtBeltTensionInput.Text); /
                    sw.WriteLine(txtBeltTensionOutput.Text);
                    if (rdbRolamento01.Checked) 
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(rdbRolamento01.Text);
                    }
                    if (rdbBucha3.Checked)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(rdbBucha3.Text);
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine(txtFriction.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtGradientForce.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtBeltStrength.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtBearingFrictionF.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtTotalForceReq.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine();

                    sw.WriteLine(txtNumberActive.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(cmbWheelsDiameter.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtFrictionWheelRail.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtTotalReacReqDrivenWheels.Text
                    sw.WriteLine(txtMinReactReqEachDrivenWheel.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtMinLoadDrivenWheel.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine(txtwLAct.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine();
                    
                    sw.Close();
                    fileStream.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully!");
                }
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, an error occurred: " + ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
         }


        private void OpenTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog AbrirArquivo = new OpenFileDialog();

                AbrirArquivo.Filter = " All files | *";
                AbrirArquivo.FilterIndex = 2;
                AbrirArquivo.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                AbrirArquivo.RestoreDirectory = true;

                var result = AbrirArquivo.ShowDialog();

                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    var NomeArquivo = AbrirArquivo.SafeFileName;
                    var Path = AbrirArquivo.FileName;

                    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

                    using (StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(AbrirArquivo.FileName))
                    {
                        txtSpeed.Text = leitor.ReadLine();  
                        txtOwnWeight.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        txtOwnWeightCounterweight.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        txtMaterialWeight.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        txtMaterialWeightWithIncrustation.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        txtRailGrad.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtBeltTensionInput.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtBeltTensionOutput.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); /
                        if (rdbRolamento01.Checked) //
                        {
                            rdbRolamento01.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rdbBucha3.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        }
                        txtFriction.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtGradientForce.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtBeltStrength.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtBearingFrictionF.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtTotalForceReq.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 

                        txtNumberActive.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        cmbWheelsDiameter.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtFrictionWheelRail.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtTotalReacReqDrivenWheels.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtMinReactReqEachDrivenWheel.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtMinLoadDrivenWheel.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("Data entered successfully!");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, an error occurred: " + ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Print da tela quando eu abro o arquivo e preencho os dados nos campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Ele mostra a mensagem que foi inserido com sucesso, mas no RadioButton ele duplica a minha seleção, e desordena os dados do grupo 2.

Comment: `if (rdbRolamento01.Checked)` isso ta errado na leitura, pra escrever faz sentido mas pra ler deveria ver o que tem no arquivo texto e setar corretamente o radio

Comment: @RicardoPontual Sabe me dizer qual seria a maneira certa de escrever para fazer a leitura no arquivo text e setar no radio?

Comment: quando grava, está gravando o text do radio, assim por exemplo `sw.WriteLine(rdbRolamento01.Text);` então precisa comparar o valor gravado, algo como `var tipo = leitor.ReadLine(); if (tipo == "Rolamento") rdbRolamento01.Checked = true;`

Comment: @RicardoPontual Deu certo o RadioButton conforme você me disse, pore´´ma estou com um problema: no segundo grupo o primeiro Textbox (Quantidade), ele fica em branco e o valor deste textbox vai para o Textbox abaixo, alterando toda a sequencia, sabe me dizer o porque isso acontece? Pois, infelizmente não consegui achar o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após as ajudas, consegui achar o meu erro, segue as correções:

No evento de Salvar tirar os espaços entre as linhas `sw.WriteLine();` para no momento de puxar os dados dos arquivos, ele saia da ordem.

E no evento de Abrir que era o problema ao invés de colocar o  `if (rdbRolamento01.Checked)`. Era necessário colocar algo para comparar com o valor gravado no arquivo texto.

Segue o código alterado:

```
        private void SaveTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SaveFileDialog dados = new SaveFileDialog();
                dados.Filter = "Arquivo texto (*.txt) | *.txt";
                dados.FilterIndex = 2;
                dados.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                dados.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (dados.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    Stream fileStream = dados.OpenFile();
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                    /
                    sw.WriteLine(txtSpeed.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtOwnWeight.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine(txtOwnWeightCounterweight.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtMaterialWeight.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine(txtMaterialWeightWithIncrustation.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtRailGrad.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtBeltTensionInput.Text); /
                    sw.WriteLine(txtBeltTensionOutput.Text);
                    if (rdbRolamento01.Checked) 
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(rdbRolamento01.Text);
                    }
                    if (rdbBucha3.Checked)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(rdbBucha3.Text);
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine(txtFriction.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtGradientForce.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtBeltStrength.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtBearingFrictionF.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtTotalForceReq.Text); 

                    sw.WriteLine(txtNumberActive.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(cmbWheelsDiameter.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtFrictionWheelRail.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtTotalReacReqDrivenWheels.Text
                    sw.WriteLine(txtMinReactReqEachDrivenWheel.Text); 
                    sw.WriteLine(txtMinLoadDrivenWheel.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine(txtwLAct.Text); 
                    
                    sw.Close();
                    fileStream.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully!");
                }
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, an error occurred: " + ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
         }


        private void OpenTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog AbrirArquivo = new OpenFileDialog();

                AbrirArquivo.Filter = " All files | *";
                AbrirArquivo.FilterIndex = 2;
                AbrirArquivo.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                AbrirArquivo.RestoreDirectory = true;

                var result = AbrirArquivo.ShowDialog();

                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    var NomeArquivo = AbrirArquivo.SafeFileName;
                    var Path = AbrirArquivo.FileName;

                    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

                    using (StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(AbrirArquivo.FileName))
                    {
                        txtSpeed.Text = leitor.ReadLine();  
                        txtOwnWeight.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        txtOwnWeightCounterweight.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        txtMaterialWeight.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        txtMaterialWeightWithIncrustation.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                        txtRailGrad.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtBeltTensionInput.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtBeltTensionOutput.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); /
                        var tipo = leitor.ReadLine();
                        if (tipo == "Rolamento") rdbRolamento01.Checked = true;                        
                        txtFriction.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtGradientForce.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtBeltStrength.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtBearingFrictionF.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtTotalForceReq.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 

                        txtNumberActive.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        cmbWheelsDiameter.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtFrictionWheelRail.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtTotalReacReqDrivenWheels.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtMinReactReqEachDrivenWheel.Text = leitor.ReadLine(); 
                        txtMinLoadDrivenWheel.Text = leitor.ReadLine();
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("Data entered successfully!");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, an error occurred: " + ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```